# Eclipse Convert APK to BAR file

Tags: eclipse-plugin, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-playbook

Few month ago i installed blackberry plugin-in eclipse for converting apk to bar and run it on blackberry playbook.before when i run apk (by adding blackberry nature)on playbook.eclipse itself made bar file along apk in bin folder.but now it does not make bar file instead it make .wrn file. 
i dont understand what is the case.wither i have missed any addional plugin or any thing else has changed.plz help thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was forgetting one step..that when i "sign apk for app world" then it converts apk to bar file ..before i was just verifing apk and loading to playbook and not was signing for app world

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: i think u didnot get my answer..i can explain u..if u have not got